# How to define a function of multiple variables in Mathematica 9.0?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Defining a function with one variable in Mathematica, is by : f[x_]. 
How do I write a function for more variables?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142730/programmatically-creating-multivariate-functions-in-mathematica and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572075/multivariate-functions-with-conditions-in-mathematica

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comma **","** separator:

```
f[x_Integer, y_Integer]
```

**[Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html)** there are more examples to make functions with default option, or some especial type, etc.